# uibutton image on the left and text on the center

Tags: ios

I am creating a button with image on the left and text on the center.
It works but somehow the background color of red doesn't cover the entire button.

```
    self.buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [self.buyButton.titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor buttonRed]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cart.png"];
    [self.buyButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.buyButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
    [self.buyButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.buyButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0);
    self.buyButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

[1]http://s23.postimg.org/g8hxmihyv/Screen_Shot_2013_08_07_at_5_45_40_PM.png "snapshot"

If i set the entire button to red, it looks like this.
[1] http://s21.postimg.org/xdwrziphv/Screen_Shot_2013_08_07_at_5_50_15_PM.png "snapshot2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're only settings the background color to red for the titleLabel. Try setting the background color of the button itself while using a custom button and changing the corner radius of the button's layer (`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`). ex:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[button.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
```

Additionally, you *may* need to change the color of the titleLabel to clearColor.

Comment: I did and it looks strange. See above.

Comment: [self.buyButton.titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.buyButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: Ah..ok..it works now. UIBUttonTypeCustom..before it was rect.